# Highcharts: annotation on y-axis

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way in Highcharts to put some sort of permanent annotation on the y-axis? Say that my y-axis goes from 0-100. Part of the data set that I get back is a min and a max, and I want to annotate those on the axis to say what the min and the max was, and I want that annotation to be retained when I zoom. I tried the Annotations plugin (http://blacklabel.github.io/annotations/), but that didn't seem to do quite what I need.

Attached Ugly, mocked up screenshot of what I would like. The Ideal Max and Ideal Min are things I already have, by using plot bands. The Min and Max annotations on the y axis are what I would like.

[image: Ugly, mocked up screenshot of what I would like. The Ideal Max and Ideal Min are things I already have, by using plot bands. The Min and Max annotations on the y axis are what I would like.]

Comment: there definitely is, i'm just not sure to point you towards label formatter functions, extra axis'/labels, and the many other options that can be used to achieve this. can you provide a screenshot or something of what you want...

Comment: I attached a mocked up screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate chart programmatically.

On load you can create a label or shape with the use of [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer). On redraw you can redraw annotations (redraw is fired on zoom):

```
function annotateChart({ text, value }) {
  const annons = this.annons;

  const label = this.renderer.label(text, 0, -9e9).attr({
    stroke: 'red',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    align: 'center',
    zIndex: 99
  }).add();

  annons.push({
    label,
    value
  });
}

function redrawAnnons() {
  const xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
  const yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

  this.annons.forEach(ann => {
    ann.label.animate({
      x: xAxis.toPixels(0),
      y: yAxis.toPixels(ann.value)
    });
  });
}
```

And chart config:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
zoomType: 'xy',
events: {
  load: function() {
    this.annons = [];

    [{
      text: 'min',
      value: 20
    }, {
      text: 'max',
      value: 85
    }].forEach(obj => {
      annotateChart.call(this, obj);
    });

    redrawAnnons.call(this)
  },
  redraw: redrawAnnons
}
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/47ao5tfz/

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks so much!